# Ajax TabContainer Question: Accessing web controls on the client side

Tags: asp.net

- What is the best way to reference controls from the clientside from within a TabPanel? I've tried using jQuery and javascript both has failed me. I've tired using the find method, but still no luck...
    SchoolSectionID  refers to a div element within one of my TabPanel controls.

  for (var a = 1; a < 4; a++) {
      var SelectControlID = "";
      var HiddenControlID = "";
      var BehaviorID = "";
      var SectionIdentifer = a;
      var SchoolSectionID = "SchoolSection" + a + "";

  ```
  /* Retrieve all select list controls from this panel. */
  var selectElements = $("#" + SchoolSectionID + "").find("select");
  alert(selectElements.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++) {

      SelectControlID = selectElements[i].id.split('_')[2];
      alert(SelectControlID);
      BehaviorID = "SchoolTypeID" + a + "";
                  InitControl(SelectControlID);
                  switch (i) {
                      case 0:
                          LoadDegreeStatus(SelectControlID);
                          HiddenControlID = "_hndSchoolStatus" + a + "";
                          RegisterOnSelectedItemEvent(SelectControlID, HiddenControlID);
                          break;
                      case 1:
                          HiddenControlID = "_hndSchoolYear" + a + "";
                          LoadSchoolYears(SelectControlID, HiddenControlID);
                          RegisterOnSelectedItemEvent(SelectControlID, HiddenControlID);
                          break;
                      case 2:
                          HiddenControlID = "_hndSchoolType" + a + "";
                          LoadSchoolTypes(SelectControlID);
                          RegisterOnChangeEvent(SelectControlID, BehaviorID, SectionIdentifer);
                          RegisterOnSelectedItemEvent(SelectControlID, HiddenControlID);
                          break;
                      case 3:
                          HiddenControlID = "_hndDiploma" + a + "";
                          LoadDiplomas(SelectControlID);
                          RegisterOnSelectedItemEvent(SelectControlID, HiddenControlID);
                          break;
                      default:
                  }
  }
  ```

  }
   
                          
                              
                                  
                                      STATUT:
                              
                                  
                              
                              
                              
                          
                          
                              
                                  
                                      ANNEE:
                              
                                  
                              
                              
                              
                          
                          
                              
                                  
                                      ETABLISSEMENT:
                              
                                  
                              
                              
                              
                          
                          
                              
                              
                              
                                  
                                  
                              
                              
                              
                          
                          
                              
                                  
                                      DIPLÔME:

Comment: Provide some code showing what you have tried so far so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Access .NET controls in Javascript by the ClientID.

```
var dotNetControl = $('<% control.ClientID %>');
```